# what are the best parameters to for the jvm settings

Tags: java, jvm

I am very new to java and jvm. I have a jvm setting as this:

```
JAVA_OPTS=""-Xmx3072m""
JAVA_OPTS=""${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:-UseVMInterruptibleIO""
JAVA_OPTS=""${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:NewSize=256m""
JAVA_OPTS=""${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:MaxNewSize=256m""
JAVA_OPTS=""${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:PermSize=256m""
JAVA_OPTS=""${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:MaxPermSize=256m""
JAVA_OPTS=""${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:+DisableExplicitGC""
```

Can someone tell me if these are ok and any room for improvement. is there any jvm setting am missing to get the optimal performance?

I thank you for any insight.

Comment: Well, *that's* subjective...tuning the JVM ***strongly*** depends on what it is you're actually doing.  Very rarely would a mere mortal need to even understand *half* of what these parameters are.

Comment: Can you expand your question to describe what kind of app you are running, and what the app does? There is no one size fits all set of tuning options. If you're in doubt, then using the defaults is better than trying to tune for a problem that you don't have (yet) or a problem that you don't understand.

Comment: there isn't  a "best settings'  that fits all applications. It depends on the application you run and your plateform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which jvm you are using. If you are using java 8, permsize and maxpermsize has been deprecated and is superseded by the -XX:MetaspaceSize and -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize options respectively. 
You are setting the newSize and maxNewSize to the same value, instead you can use option -Xmnsize, which sets the newSize and maxNewSize to same value.

DisableExplicitGC is to disable System.gc() calls within the code, so if you want to disable those calls, you might consider removing it from the code.

Answer (score 1):

If there were a single set of "best parameters" then the JVM developers would include it as a default, and would not offer options to specify different parameters. That would mean happier users, and less work for them!

*The fact that these parameters exist* indicates that the JVM developers know that **a single set of parameter values does not fit all applications** - and therefore, they have invested significant effort to allow you to change it.

The parameters that you currently indicate are fine for a server that requires a lot of RAM, wants to set up a large perm-space (possibly to cover classloader bugs; is that a webapp you are running?), and does not want IO to be interrupted by the vm (although that particular flag seems to only work on Solaris). You can [look up all arguments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) here.